# How can I create a Core Data file before runtime?

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I have a bunch of data that I want to store in a Core Data file. The problem is that It only gets created at runtime. How can I create it before, save it into my bundle, and then display it to the user?

Comment: So what's the problem with adding it to core data in runtime then reloading the view?

Comment: Thats not what I'm asking. I'm asking if there is a way to save a core data file to the bundle, and read from that, instead of generating the file at runtime.

Comment: sadly i dont think so, one of the many reasons i use sqlite instead. Because that is just a disgusting *feature*.

Comment: If you generate a file and add it to you project, sure. Or add a plist / JSON file and read that in on first launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this by running my app (or a utility written just for this purpose) in the simulator during development and populating it with its pre-set information.  I then find the file on disk, put it in my project, and make sure it is included in the "Copy files" build phase.

At start up, I look for the file in the app bundle, and copy it to where CoreData expects it...that is, some writable location.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to use a property list (.plist) file that contains arrays and dictionaries of the "default data" I wish to preload, then on first run load that default data in.

I use code in my core data stack to check the plist file against existing default data and, in the case that I have updated the plist file with some additional default data (for subsequent production release), this is added.

I also use code in my core data stack to change or delete default data as necessary, but this is data specific.